# How to verify an input file name on a form using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to verify that an input file in an html form is an image, I've made the follow code inside the html page, but it doesn't work...

```
 script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
    function valida(f){
        var campo = f.immagine.value;
        //window.alert(campo);
        var er = /^+.[\.]([jpg]|[gif]|[png])$/;
        if(er.test(campo)) {
            windows.alert("espressione regolare corretta");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            windows.alert("espressione regolare non corretta");
            f.immagine.style = "color:#F00";
            return false;   
        }
    }
/script
```

My html code:

```
form  onsubmit="return valida(this)" action="inserisci_articolo1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    input type="file" name="immagine" id="immagine" /
/form
```

Comment: What is your question? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What about `.jpeg`? or `.PNG`?

Comment: when i clic on the submit button of the form with an incorrect file (for example a txt file) the function have to "block" the link and to color the text of the file name in red, but seem that don't enter in the "if" and "else" block...

Answer (score 4):

```
var er = /^.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i;
```

There you go. The thing is that you put the `.+` at the beginning in the wrong order, and should not have encapsulated jpg/gif/png and the point in `[]`. Now the regex should work for `*.jp(e)g`, `*.gif` and `*.png`. I also added `jpeg` in the list and made the regex case-insensitive.

Also, note that it's `window` not `windows`, and `f.immagine.style` is an object, not a string, so use something like `f.immagine.style.color = "#f00";`

*Also, you have to make sure the user inputs an image, because any file with modified extension will pass this test.*

Comment: `jpe?g` saves you one alternation.